# macOS g++ no longer usable after updating Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

After updating to Xcode 15, I cannot use g++.

I downgraded to Xcode 14.3.1 and "brew reinstall gcc", result was not changed.

When I use g++ xxx.cpp the below error is displayed.

```
-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min
0  0x105edff43  __assert_rtn + 64
1  0x105de1f43  ld::AtomPlacement::findAtom(unsigned char, unsigned long long, ld::AtomPlacement::AtomLoc const*&, long long&) const + 1411
2  0x105dfe431  ld::InputFiles::SliceParser::parseObjectFile(mach_o::Header const*) const + 19745
3  0x105e0eb71  ld::InputFiles::parseAllFiles(void (ld::AtomFile const*) block_pointer)::$_7::operator()(unsigned long, ld::FileInfo const&) const + 657
4  0x7ff80752f066  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 8
5  0x7ff80754218f  _dispatch_apply_invoke_and_wait + 213
6  0x7ff807541692  _dispatch_apply_with_attr_f + 1207
7  0x7ff807541847  dispatch_apply + 45
8  0x105ea7972  ld::AtomFileConsolidator::parseFiles(bool) + 370
9  0x105e2ed67  main + 12263
ld: Assertion failed: (resultIndex < sectData.atoms.size()), function findAtom, file Relocations.cpp, line 1336.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

Comment: Based on [the source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/36eec7995b4d53083c3ee7824bd765b5eba8b1a1/gcc/config/darwin.h#L586-L587), I believe this is built into the `gcc` project source and as such, is likely a bug with `gcc`.  I would recommend filing a bug report here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi.  Since it's an open source project, I would also strongly recommend that you consider offering to help patch it.  If it's a bug with `gcc`, Homebrew will eventually receive the patch.

Comment: @tresf That informational warning is irrelevant to the failed assertion.

Comment: You need to upgrade homebrew gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I temporary fixed with below flow.

```bash
$ brew install gcc
```

This results in gcc with apple clang.
As a result, following command worked well.

```bash
$ g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue, updating gcc works pretty well.

```
brew install gcc
```

This command will install, or update the current version on GCC accordingly, you don't need to delete the current version and install the new one.
I am currently using an M1 MacBook, and it works pretty well!